# How do I get wallet balance using xPub address with blockain.info api?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

I am using blockchain.info api. I know how to get wallet balance using wallet id and password.

Couldn't find how to find wallet balance using my xPub address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api):

> Multi Address
>
> `https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?active=$address|$address`
>
> Multiple addresses divided by |
>
> Address can be base58 or xpub
>
> Optional limit parameter to show n transactions e.g. &n=50 (Default: 50, Max: 100)
>
> Optional offset parameter to skip the first n transactions e.g. &offset=100 (Page 2 for limit 50)